# How to create an excel formulae with 2 letter colums

Tags: excel

I have an excel spreadsheet that goes through a-z then onto the double letter columns.

I am creating a running leader board so I need the persons name which is in column B and their score which is in column BL.

I have 2 problems.

1. to stop the problem of a tied score I have created a new column in BM and used the formula =B2+ROW()/100. As the new column is in a double letter column it won't let me do it. I get a #name? Error.
2. when trying to put the people and their scores in the running table I get the same error as the scores I need are in the double letter column.

I have tried it using the single letter columns and it works fine.

Is there a way to use a similar formula to allow for the double letter columns or is it easier to split the sheet up into the single letter columns?

Comment: Not sure I understand. `=B2+ROW()/100` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Columns as you describe as containing *double letters* (better defined `Column()>26`  behave **exactly** the same as all previous columns. Something else is causing those #Name. My guess is that you are copy/pasting a formula wrong (perhaps referencing a column that would be before column A).

Whatever your issue is, it doesn't relate to the column # being over `26` or greater than Column `Z`.